# [Server]Is it possible to detect power button pressed in a program wrote by ourself in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: c, linux, shell, ubuntu-20.04

I want to run a program on a server.
But I don't want it shoutdown immediately after I press power button.

The expected result is server could finish program properly and get the test result. Then shutdown finally.

The program running environment would be under the Ubuntu 20.04 Virtual Terminals(TTY).

I have tried some methods on the web I found (like change some system files). But it just disabled the power button function. I can't connect how to detect in my program.

I am curious is it possible to detect power button pressed or not in the program we wrote?

If it is possible, how to do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't. There are several ways that can trigger shutdown and the power button is only one of them. Instead, learn about how system shutdown works under systemd, and write a systemd service file that handles shutdown of your application gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for your comment very much!!  I will study systmed first and try to use.

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred to comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Have you tried to modify the `/usr/share/doc/acpid/examples/powerbtn.sh` script?

[This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/acpid) seems to describe how to proceed. But I haven't gone deep.

Comment: I have tried another path to create powerbtn.sh. But it doesn't work. I will try the file you said, if the file does exist in my server. Thanks for your reply!